# fill two dimensionell boolean array

Tags: java, arrays, boolean, fill

I need to fill a boolean array one by one. Here is the code I have for filling the first row to true, one by one and it's working. I want to do this with a loop or something so I don't need all the if, else if statements. Any suggestions of how to do that?

```
public class Airline {

boolean seat[][] = new boolean[2][3];



Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public void start() {
    while (true) {
        makeReservation();
    }
}

public void makeReservation() {
System.out.println("Press 1 or 2");
    int klass = input.nextInt();
    if (klass == 1) {
        firstClassSeat();
    } else {
        economySeat();
    }
}

public void firstClassSeat() // assign a first class seat
{
    for (int row = 0; row < seat.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < seat[row].length; col++) {

        }
        if (seat[0][0] == false) 
        {

            seat[0][0] = true;  // assign seat
            System.out.println("You now have seat 00 in first class");

            break;

        }
        if (seat[0][1] == false) {

            seat[0][1] = true;  // assign seat
            System.out.println("You now have seat 01 in first class");

            break;
        } else if (seat[0][2] == false) {

            seat[0][2] = true;  // assign seat
            System.out.println("You now have seat 02 in first class");

            break;
        } else {
     System.out.println("The plane is full");
            int val = input.nextInt();
            if (val == 1) {
                economySeat();
                start();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Thank you and welcome again");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void economySeat() // assign an economy seat
{
    for (int row = 0; row < seat.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < seat[row].length; col++) {

        }
        if (seat[1][0] == false) 
        {

            seat[1][0] = true;  // assign seat
            System.out.println("You now have seat 01 in first class");

            break;

        }
        if (seat[1][1] == false) {

            seat[1][1] = true;  // assign seat
            System.out.println("You now have seat 02 in first class");

            break;
        } else if (seat[1][2] == false) {

            seat[1][2] = true;  // assign seat
            System.out.println("You now have seat 02 in first class");

            break;
        } else {
       System.out.println("The economy class is full ");
            int val = input.nextInt();
            if (val == 1) {
                economySeat();
                start();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Thank you and welcome again");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

Here's what I did with the firstclass method

```
public void firstClassSeat() {

    for (int row = 0; row < seat.length; row++) {

        for (int col = 0; col < seat[row].length; col++) {

            if (!seat[row][col]) 
            {

                seat[row][col] = true;  
  System.out.println("You have place number 0" + row + " in the Firstclass");

                break;

            } else if (seat[0][2]) {
                if (seat[1][2]) {
                    System.out.println("The plane is full, welcome again");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            } else {
 System.out.println("First class is full. Economyclass? 1 for yes 2 for no");       
                int choice = input.nextInt();
                if (choice == 1) {
                    economySeat();
                    start();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Thank you and welcome again");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

But I don't know how to do so it only makes the array true one by one. This code takes two at the time. Any suggestions?

Comment: Post the entire class.

Comment: I posted the entire class. It's not finished yet. I just want to know how to change the code so I don't need all the if and else if statements.

Comment: you wanna do true false true false, something like that in each line?

Comment: This code is working just as I want. I was just wondering if there is another way I can fill the seats  instead of all the if and else statements

Comment: Why use `if(foo == true)` if `foo` is a boolean...? You dont need to check if the value is false- no matter what happens once the code runs it will be true

Comment: What is your logic? Simply find first not assigned (`false`) seat and assign it (turn to `true`)?

Comment: @ PM 77-1 Yes, that is the logic. I want to fill the boolean array until all of it is true and then exit the program

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of very bad conventions in your code, but what you're looking for is

```
for(int i = 0; i < seat.length; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < seat[i].length; j++)
        seat[i][j] = newBool;
```